# Keep the OnTouchListener subscribed to motion events even those started outside the view?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to implement a `cut action` like fruit ninja or cut the rope.

My view should intercept these `cuts` (let's call them swipes) events. I set a simple `onSwipeTouchListener`, it worked fine, but only when the `Motionevent.ACTION_DOWN` is made (swipe started) inside the view, which is sad!

I don't know why the system don't dispatch `ACTION_MOVE` events made inside the view, unless the `ACTION_DOWN` was inside it too.

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

All I could do is forcing the dispatch overriding the dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) method from activity :

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    dim = new Dimensions();
    dim.set(ev);
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    if(ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        if(dim.isInside(sg)){
            if(!ActionDownPassed) {
                ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
                ActionDownPassed = true;
            }
        }else if(ActionDownPassed){
            ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
        }

        sg.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    if(ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) ActionDownPassed = false;

    return false;
}
```

It works, but **I don't think it's a good idea**.

PS: the Dimensions class :

```
public class Dimensions {

public int width;
public int height;

public Dimensions() {}

public Dimensions(int w, int h) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

public Dimensions(Dimensions p) {
    this.width = p.width;
    this.height = p.height;
}

public final void set(int w, int h) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

public final void set(Dimensions d) {
    this.width = d.width;
    this.height = d.height;
}

public final void set(MotionEvent e){
    this.width = (int) e.getX();
    this.height = (int) e.getY();
}

public final boolean equals(int w, int h) {
    return this.width == w && this.height == h;
}

public final boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Dimensions && (o == this || equals(((Dimensions)o).width, ((Dimensions)o).height));
}

public boolean isInside(View v){
    int[] a = new int[2] ;
    v.getLocationOnScreen(a);
    int w = v.getWidth();
    int h = v.getHeight();
    if(   a[0] <= this.width
            && this.width <= (a[0] + w)
        && a[1] <= this.height
            && this.height <= (a[1] + h) )
        return true;
    else return false;

}
```

}